# Load "Vanilla" Javascript Libraries into Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, commonjs

There are some third party Javascript libraries that have some functionality I would like to use in a Node.js server. (Specifically I want to use a QuadTree javascript library that I found.) But these libraries are just straightforward `.js` files and not "Node.js libraries".

As such, these libraries don't follow the `exports.var_name` syntax that Node.js expects for its modules. As far as I understand that means when you do `module = require('module_name');` or `module = require('./path/to/file.js');` you'll end up with a module with no publicly accessible functions, etc.

My question then is "How do I load an arbitrary javascript file into Node.js such that I can utilize its functionality without having to rewrite it so that it does do `exports`?"

I'm very new to Node.js so please let me know if there is some glaring hole in my understanding of how it works.

---

**EDIT**: Researching into things more and I now see that the module loading pattern that Node.js uses is actually part of a recently developed standard for loading Javascript libraries called [CommonJS](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Modules/1.1). It says this right on the [module doc page for Node.js](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.1/api/modules.html), but I missed that until now.

It may end up being that the answer to my question is "wait until your library's authors get around to writing a CommonJS interface or do it your damn self."

Comment: related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22898080/how-to-create-an-enviroment-agnostic-javascript-library

Answer (score 78, accepted):

There is a much better method than using `eval`: the [`vm`](https://nodejs.org/api/vm.html) module.

For example, here is my `execfile` module, which evaluates the script at `path` in either `context` or the global context:

```
var vm = require("vm");
var fs = require("fs");
module.exports = function(path, context) {
  context = context || {};
  var data = fs.readFileSync(path);
  vm.runInNewContext(data, context, path);
  return context;
}
```

And it can be used like this:

```
> var execfile = require("execfile");
> // `someGlobal` will be a global variable while the script runs
> var context = execfile("example.js", { someGlobal: 42 });
> // And `getSomeGlobal` defined in the script is available on `context`:
> context.getSomeGlobal()
42
> context.someGlobal = 16
> context.getSomeGlobal()
16
```

Where `example.js` contains:

```
function getSomeGlobal() {
    return someGlobal;
}
```

The big advantage of this method is that you've got complete control over the global variables in the executed script: you can pass in custom globals (via `context`), and all the globals created by the script will be added to `context`. Debugging is also easier because syntax errors and the like will be reported with the correct file name.

Comment: Does `runInNewContext` use the global context if `context` (otherwise referred to as `sandbox`, in docs) is undefined? (this point was not made clear by any docs I found)

Comment: It seems that, for the purpose of playing with a third-party library ignorant of Node or the CommonJS pattern, Christopher's eval method <http://stackoverflow.com/a/9823294/1450294> works well. What benefits can the `vm` module offer in this case?

Comment: See my updates for a description of why this method is better than eval.

Comment: this _totally_ rocks -- it allowed me to instantly re-use my web-based non-module code for a server-side implementation that emails the outputs [on a schedule] instead of displaying them on a webpage.  All the web code used the loose-augmenting module pattern and script injection -- so this works so fine !!

Comment: How can we use this in Node.js if example.js depends on example1.js library?

Comment: The npm module rewire is really good for this.  It's basically the same idea.  Instead of:

var dep = require('someDep')

you do

var context = rewire('someDep');
context.__get__('someDep').

We use it here, mostly as a way of mocking objects  (you can override functions via the context), but same idea.

Answer (score 82):

Here's what I think is the 'rightest' answer for this situation.

Say you have a script file called `quadtree.js`.

You should build a custom `node_module` that has this sort of directory structure...

```
./node_modules/quadtree/quadtree-lib/
./node_modules/quadtree/quadtree-lib/quadtree.js
./node_modules/quadtree/quadtree-lib/README
./node_modules/quadtree/quadtree-lib/some-other-crap.js
./node_modules/quadtree/index.js
```

Everything in your `./node_modules/quadtree/quadtree-lib/` directory are files from your 3rd party library.

Then your `./node_modules/quadtree/index.js` file will just load that library from the filesystem and do the work of exporting things properly.

```
var fs = require('fs');

// Read and eval library
filedata = fs.readFileSync('./node_modules/quadtree/quadtree-lib/quadtree.js','utf8');
eval(filedata);

/* The quadtree.js file defines a class 'QuadTree' which is all we want to export */

exports.QuadTree = QuadTree
```

Now you can use your `quadtree` module like any other node module...

```
var qt = require('quadtree');
qt.QuadTree();
```

---

I like this method because there's no need to go changing any of the source code of your 3rd party library--so it's easier to maintain. All you need to do on upgrade is look at their source code and ensure that you are still exporting the proper objects.

Comment: Just found your answer (making a multiplayer game and needed to include JigLibJS, our physics engine, on the server as well as the client) you saved me a LOT of time and hassle. Thank you!

Comment: If you follow this exactly, keep in mind that it's pretty easy to accidentally obliterate your node_modules folder using NPM, especially if you don't check it into SCM. Definitely consider putting your QuadTree library in a separate repository, then `npm link`ing it into your application. Then it's handled as if it were a native Node.js package.

Comment: @btown, could you expand a bit for the newbies like me what SCM and npm link do exactly that prevents the potential issue you mention?

Comment: Is this really neccessary if I just want to include a script?

Comment: @flion replying to the old comment for others ref as I'm sure you'll know you answer by now. SCM - Source Control Management (e.g. GIT) and a link to a quick but good demo of [npm link](https://egghead.io/lessons/node-js-using-npm-link-to-use-node-modules-that-are-in-progress)

Answer (score 31):

The simplest way is: `eval(require('fs').readFileSync('./path/to/file.js', 'utf8'));`
This works great for testing in the interactive shell.

Comment: Cheers Mate! Helped a lot

Comment: This is also the quickest way, and sometimes quick-and-dirty is what you need. Between this and David's answer, this SO page is an excellent resource.

Answer (score 5):

AFAIK, that is indeed how modules must be loaded.
However, instead of tacking all exported functions onto the `exports` object, you can also tack them onto `this` (what would otherwise be the global object).

So, if you want to keep the other libraries compatible, you can do this:

```
this.quadTree = function () {
  // the function's code
};
```

or, when the external library already has its own namespace, e.g. `jQuery` (not that you can use *that* in a server-side environment):

```
this.jQuery = jQuery;
```

In a non-Node environment, `this` would resolve to the global object, thus making it a global variable... which it already was.  So it shouldn't break anything.

**Edit**:
James Herdman has a [nice writeup](http://jherdman.github.com/2010-04-05/understanding-nodejs-require.html) about node.js for beginners, which also mentions this.

Comment: The 'this' trick sounds like a good way to make things more portable so that Node.js libraries can be used outside of Node.js, but it still means I need to manually change my javascript libraries to support the Node.js require syntax.

Comment: @ChrisW.: yes, you will have to manually change your libraries.  Personally, I also would've liked a second mechanism to include external files, one that automatically converted the included file's global namespace to the imported namespace.  Perhaps you could file a RFE to the Node developers?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if I'll actually end up using this because it's a rather hacky solution, but one way around this is to build a little mini-module importer like this...

In the file `./node_modules/vanilla.js`:

```
var fs = require('fs');

exports.require = function(path,names_to_export) {
    filedata = fs.readFileSync(path,'utf8');
    eval(filedata);
    exported_obj = {};
    for (i in names_to_export) {
        to_eval = 'exported_obj[names_to_export[i]] = ' 
            + names_to_export[i] + ';'
        eval(to_eval); 
    }
    return exported_obj;
}
```

Then when you want to use your library's functionality you'll need to manually choose which names to export.

So for a library like the file `./lib/mylibrary.js`...

```
function Foo() { //Do something... }
biz = "Blah blah";
var bar = {'baz':'filler'};
```

When you want to use its functionality in your Node.js code...

```
var vanilla = require('vanilla');
var mylibrary = vanilla.require('./lib/mylibrary.js',['biz','Foo'])
mylibrary.Foo // <-- this is Foo()
mylibrary.biz // <-- this is "Blah blah"
mylibrary.bar // <-- this is undefined (because we didn't export it)
```

Don't know how well this would all work in practice though.

Comment: Hey, wow: a down-voted (not by me) and up-voted answer by the same user for the same question! There should be a badge for that! ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I was able to make it work by updating their script, very easily, simply adding `module.exports =` where appropriate...

For example, I took *their* file and I copied to './libs/apprise.js'. Then where it starts with

```
function apprise(string, args, callback){
```

I assigned the function to `module.exports =` thus:

```
module.exports = function(string, args, callback){
```

Thus I'm able to import the library into *my* code like this:

```
window.apprise = require('./libs/apprise.js');
```

And I was good to go.  YMMV, this was with [webpack](https://webpack.github.io).

Answer (score 0):

A simple `include(filename)` function with better error messaging (stack, filename etc.) for `eval`, in case of errors:

```
var fs = require('fs');
// circumvent nodejs/v8 "bug":
// https://github.com/PythonJS/PythonJS/issues/111
// http://perfectionkills.com/global-eval-what-are-the-options/
// e.g. a "function test() {}" will be undefined, but "test = function() {}" will exist
var globalEval = (function() {
    var isIndirectEvalGlobal = (function(original, Object) {
        try {
            // Does `Object` resolve to a local variable, or to a global, built-in `Object`,
            // reference to which we passed as a first argument?
            return (1, eval)('Object') === original;
        } catch (err) {
            // if indirect eval errors out (as allowed per ES3), then just bail out with `false`
            return false;
        }
    })(Object, 123);
    if (isIndirectEvalGlobal) {
        // if indirect eval executes code globally, use it
        return function(expression) {
            return (1, eval)(expression);
        };
    } else if (typeof window.execScript !== 'undefined') {
        // if `window.execScript exists`, use it
        return function(expression) {
            return window.execScript(expression);
        };
    }
    // otherwise, globalEval is `undefined` since nothing is returned
})();

function include(filename) {
    file_contents = fs.readFileSync(filename, "utf8");
    try {
        //console.log(file_contents);
        globalEval(file_contents);
    } catch (e) {
        e.fileName = filename;
        keys = ["columnNumber", "fileName", "lineNumber", "message", "name", "stack"]
        for (key in keys) {
            k = keys[key];
            console.log(k, " = ", e[k])
        }
        fo = e;
        //throw new Error("include failed");
    }
}
```

But it even gets dirtier with nodejs: you need to specify this:

```
export NODE_MODULE_CONTEXTS=1
nodejs tmp.js
```

Otherwise you cannot use global variables in files included with `include(...)`.