# Requiring Javascript modules from both Node and Browser runtimes

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using Nodejs for writing some sample programs, which should also be callable from a browser. I am facing an issue with calling JavaScript files from within Nodejs, in a way that would be compatible with browser JS semantics as well (so `require`, which is Node specific, won't do the job).

Suppose I have three .js files: "A.js", "B.js" and "C.js". "A.js" is written in Node.  "B.js" and "C.js" are written in pure JavaScript (that is, they should be callable from a browser).

I need to call a function b() present in "B.js" from "A.js". So I eval() "B.js" exporting the method b(). This works properly. The problem occurs when my function b() in "B.js" calls a function c() in "C.js".

```
B.js:

function b()
{
    console.log('In function b');
    c();
}

C.js:

function c()
{
    console.log('In function c');
}
```

How do i make sure the dependancy is resolved? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!!!

Comment: Can you clarify what is the difference between the "pure" JavaScript and "node" one?

Comment: pure javascript has no require() or module.exports. We can make a function call using the function name along with the namespace, but node does not allow it. We need to require the files we need to use and export the modules/functions which needs to be used in other js files.

Answer (score 1):

In node.js, there is the [`require`](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html) function, allowing you to require a file and use what's exported.

C.js:

```
function c() {
    console.log('In function c');
}

// This is the exported object
module.exports = {
    c: c
};
```

B.js:

```
function b() {
    var c = require('./c.js');
    // "c" is now the exported object

    console.log('In function b');
    c.c();
}

module.exports = {
    b: b
};
```

A.js:

```
var b = require('./b.js');

b.b(); // "In function b" "In function c"
```

You should definitely read up on how to handle modules in node.js: http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html

Comment: My B.js and C.js are Javascript files not node. Javascript does not support require and module.exports.

Comment: @user1999645 Javascript itself doesn't support anything. Do you mean that B.js and C.js are browser files? Why do you want to do that?

Comment: They are browser independent files. I need to execute them using Node through command line. require() and module.exports are Nodejs specific, they are not supported in javascript. My B.js and C.js is written in Javascript as a generic framework code and it should be possible for me to call it from Node or a Browser using ExtJs

Comment: @user1999645 you should update your question then. It clearly wasn't clear :)

Comment: Sure thanks!!!! But I am still wondering why did Nodejs want to complicate things. Why cant a module be accessed directly like how its done in normal Javascript files. Why do we have to export modules and variables.

Comment: @user1999645: it is because with a module system you can create reusable modules and use them easily as npm packages

Comment: Thanks Florian and Spoike... :)

Answer (score 1):

You can load the plain vanilla javascript file manually and `eval` it. In your case you could create an node module that loads the pure javascript files. Like this:

**bc.js**:

```
var fs = require('fs');

// load and eval b.js and c.js
eval(fs.readFileSync('./b.js','utf8') + fs.readFileSync('./c.js','utf8'));

// put function b and c in exports
module.exports = {
    b : b,
    c : c
};
```

So whenever you require bc.js, you'll get both the `b` and `c` function and `b` can use the `c` function.

For further details see the following question: [Load "Vanilla" Javascript Libraries into Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171213/load-vanilla-javascript-libraries-into-node-js)