# NodeJS, TypeScript and typescript-collections

Tags: node.js, collections, typescript

I'm trying to use the Dictionary class from from [typescript-collections](https://github.com/basarat/typescript-collections) within NodeJS:

```
/// <reference path="../../../scripts/collections.ts" />
var collections = require('../../../scripts/collections');

export class AsyncProcessorCommand implements interfaces.IAsyncProcessorCommand
{
    public static Type = 'RabbitMon.AsyncProcessorCommand:RabbitMon';
    public GetType = () => 'RabbitMon.AsyncProcessorCommand:RabbitMon';

    public ID: string;

    constructor(public Action: string, public Arguments?: collections.Dictionary<string, string>) {
        this.ID = uuid.v4();

        this.Arguments = new collections.Dictionary<string, string>();
        //I've also tried the following
        //this.Arguments = new collections.Dictionary<string, string>((key: string) => sha1(key));
    }
}
```

But I keep getting the following error on the `new Dictionary`:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Anyone know what's going on here?  I'm also perfectly happy to substitute a better working TS collections library...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a [internal vs external modules](https://typescript.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Modules%20in%20TypeScript) problem.

The TypeScript Collections library is written as an *internal module* -- a standard JavaScript file that you could just throw in to a `script` tag in a webpage.

Node's `require`, however, is expecting an CommonJS-compatible file that will assign something to `exports`, in other words an *external module*. What's happening is that node.js finds `collections.js`, executes it, and returns you back the `exports` object from evaluating the file. Because it's just a regular JS file, the exported object is `{}` -- empty.

The best fix would be:

1. Replace your reference to `collections.ts` with one to `collections.d.ts`, just for correctness's sake (run `tsc --d collection.ts` to generate this file)
2. Use [some solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171213/load-vanilla-javascript-libraries-into-node-js) for loading "vanilla" JS files in node. A good one-liner (from the linked question) is `eval(require('fs').readFileSync('./path/to/file.js', 'utf8'));`