# Can I use c3.js / nvd3.js in angular 2.0 beta ? import seems incompatible with system.js

Tags: d3.js, typescript, angular, nvd3.js, c3.js

I am evaluating angular 2.0 beta (with typescript) and tried to include some libraries via the module system. But somehow this does not work for `c3.js` / `nv.d3.js`.
Can anyone bump me into the right direction on how to `c3.js` / `nv.d3.js` to work?

- tsconfig.json has `"module": "system"` (recommended by Angular 2.0)
- tsconfig.json has `"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true` (allows synthetic default import of d3.js)
- `import d3 from 'd3'` works
- `import c3 from 'c3'` does not work
- `import nv from 'nvd3'` does not work
- The `c3.js` site says import via `AMD` and `require.js` is possible.
- The `system.js` site says it can import `AMD` modules as well

I am no JS pro, but there is no export statement in `c3.js` / `nv.d3.js` file, also there is no typescript definition in `tsd`. I'd create one and share it, but am not familiar enough with the concepts needed.

Answer (score 1):

Seems I have to wait for the library developers to add a .d.ts declaration or add an `export`. Possible solutions for the meantime seem to be:

this:
[Load "Vanilla" Javascript Libraries into Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171213/load-vanilla-javascript-libraries-into-node-js)

or: just declare c3 / nv and assume it's there at runtime

- add to index.html: `<script src="libs/c3.js"></script>`
- and in typescript: `declare var c3;`
- add to index.html: `<script src="libs/nv.d3.js"></script>`
- and in typescript: `declare var nv;`

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Angular2 2.0.0-beta.17 and in a similar situation, building a proof of concept app with graphs and charts.

First, I imported the libraries using npm.

Next, these libraries are untyped Javascript but we can do something about that. if you are using [Typings](https://github.com/typings/typings) (and I recommend it) you can add these definitions to your typings.json (mine are under ambient):

```
"d3": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/d3/d3.d.ts",
"nvd3": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/nvd3/nvd3.d.ts",
"c3": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/c3/c3.d.ts
```

I also had trouble importing.  So, as a workaround I declared them:

declare var d3, nv: any;

Also, have a look at [Krispo's ng2-nvd3 project](https://github.com/krispo/ng2-nvd3) which supplies an nvd3 component for Angular2

This project only worked for after I made the declarations changes.

I hope this helps -- I'm learning Angular2 myself so if anyone has some best practices, please share. The "declare... any" workaround does not seem optimal.

Thanks,
Cody

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are installing nvd3 as an npm package.
In the file where you bootstrap your app module do :

```
import 'nvd3/build/nv.d3';

import {enableProdMode} from '@angular/core';
import {platformBrowserDynamic} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import {AppModule} from './app';

declare var process: any;
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  enableProdMode();
} else {
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

And in the component .ts file do :

```
declare var nv:any;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I implemented c3 chart in Ionic 2 -- similar to what Rob mentioned earlier :

Include the following links to index.html

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/js/c3.min.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/d3.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/c3.min.js"></script>
```

Below is the implementation in the .ts file:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
declare var c3;
declare var d3;

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'graph.html'
})

export class GraphC3 {
  constructor() {

  }

ngOnInit() {
    let chartoutput = c3.generate({
        bindto: '#chart',
        data: {
        columns: [
            ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
            ['data2', 50, 20, 10, 40, 15, 25]
        ]
        }
    });
}

}
```

In your graph.html file includes

```
<div id="chart"></div>
```

Comment: Here is an example :

http://plnkr.co/edit/aQfdcMtAFAKDtvjhj22v?p=preview&open=app%2Fapp.component.ts