# Load “Vanilla” Javascript Libraries into Node.js = 'Unexpected token export'

Tags: javascript, node.js, commonjs

**Building on related issue:** [Load "Vanilla" Javascript Libraries into Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171213/load-vanilla-javascript-libraries-into-node-js)

I'm trying to load a 'Vanilla' Javascript library 'rsa.js' into NodeJS, using the method described by Chris W. in the question above. In essence I've created a custom node_modules directory like this:

```
./node_modules/rsa/rsa-lib/rsa.js
./node_modules/rsa/rsa-lib/README
./node_modules/rsa/index.js
```

Only problem is, compiling the module fails on the last line of rsa.js:

```
undefined:836
export default rsa;
SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
```

**rsa.js**

```
var rsa = {};
 (function(rsa) {

   ...

})(rsa);
console.log("rsa",rsa);
export default rsa;
```

**index.js**

```
var fs = require('fs');

// Read and eval library
filedata = fs.readFileSync('./node_modules/rsa/rsa-lib/rsa.js','utf8');
eval(filedata);

/* The rsa.js file defines a class 'rsa' which is all we want to export */
exports.rsa = rsa
```

Any suggestions how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error 'Unexpected token export' is caused because the library is using

`export default thingToExport;`

instead of

`module.exports = thingToExport`

This is an ES6 feature not supported by Node (yet), so when Node tries to run the code, it throws an error.

**How to solve:** try modifying the last line of the library so it says `module.exports = rsa;`.

I should add, though, that `eval` is not a good way to load a library into your own code. That is what `require` is for. If you have installed this library with `npm i` and it is in your node_modules, you should be able to load it into your code with `var rsa = require('rsa');`.

Again though, if you're not transpiling the code, it may have problems with `export default`, so you will probably want to change that to `module.exports` either way.

Comment: Brilliant, swapping it for module.exports = rsa; did the trick. Also good point about the eval(), though not sure you can 'require' a vanilla javascript library...

Comment: You can require your own JS files using `require('./path/to/file.js')`, so I think you should be able to `require` someone else's javascript