# Loading Vanilla JS library in NodeJS = undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, soap

**Building on related issue:** [Load "Vanilla" Javascript Libraries into Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171213/load-vanilla-javascript-libraries-into-node-js)

I'm trying to load [jQuery.soap](https://github.com/doedje/jquery.soap) as a NodeJS module. I have followed the steps in the linked issue but I'm having some problems calling the functions. The Soap plugins define:

```
return $.soap = soap;
```

To call the function. So I have created an index.js with this code:

```
var fs = require('fs');

// Read and eval library
filedata = fs.readFileSync('./node_modules/jquery.soap/jquerysoap-  lib/jquery.soap.js','utf8');
eval(filedata);

exports.Soap = $.soap;
```

Then I'm loading it this way in my nodeJS file.

```
 var Soap = require('jquery.soap');
```

and using it this way:

```
Soap({
    url: myurl,
    appendMethodToURL: false,
    SOAPAction: '',
    ....
)};
```

And I'm getting a 'undefined is not a function'. Am I exporting correctly? I have tried to put

```
exports.Soap = soap;
```

instead of

```
exports.Soap = $.soap;
```

But still not working. Once I do the readFileSync should be able to call $.soap?
Thanks in advance

Edit: In my VanillaJS module I have something like:

```
function($){
    function soap (options) {
    }
return $.soap = soap;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't import/export correctly. You export 'Soap' as a member of the module, but then import 'Soap' as the entire module in which 'Soap' is only a member.

You should either go:

```
exports = $.soap;
```

or:

```
var Soap = require('jquery.soap').Soap;
```

BTW call it (lower cased) 'soap'. Don't break conventions.

Comment: I have put 'exports = $.soap;' inside the index.js of my module but the problem persists. Also tried with the other option and still not working. =(

Comment: @Sergiodiaz53 have you debbuged "exports.Soap = $.soap;" and verified that $.soap is not undefined?

Comment: I have updated my question with some info of the structure of my JS library. At that point $.soap works but in my index.js $.soap is undefined. I have tried to put exports.module = soap just before the return $.soap in the library but still 'not defined'