# Can't load Backbone.DOMStorage using require keyword

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js, commonjs

I need some help because i'm fairly new to javascript and nodejs world and i'm stuck..

I have a nodejs app project where I installed dependencies (npm install) and then in my .js file, I load my modules like : `var Backbone = require('backbone')` and it works well.

But then i tried to install Backbone.DOMStorage (https://github.com/mikeedwards/Backbone.DOMStorage) module...

I did `npm install https://github.com/mikeedwards/Backbone.DOMStorage`and installation was Ok (js file is present in the node_modules folder), but when I try to load it with `require('Backbone.DOMStorage')` it failed to find and load the module...

From what I understood after many searches, it seems that the plugin isn't CommonJS compliant..

So how can I transform this script to be able to use it like any other module ??

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I will show you 4 ways do what you want.

**First way**

Its a js plugin that's why you need to add it to your HTML page like this.
Include Backbone.domStorage after having included Backbone.js:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="backbone.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="backbone.domStorage.js"></script>
```

and use it like this

```
window.SomeCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    localStorage: new Backbone.LocalStorage("SomeLocalCollection"), // Unique name within your app.

    // ... everything else is normal.
```

});

**Second way**
If you're using browserify.

Install using npm install backbone.localstorage, and require the module.

```
Backbone.LocalStorage = require("backbone.localstorage");
```

**third way**

RequireJS

Include RequireJS:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/require.js"></script>
```

RequireJS config:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        jquery: "lib/jquery",
        underscore: "lib/underscore",
        backbone: "lib/backbone",
        localstorage: "lib/backbone.localStorage"
    }
});
```

Define your collection as a module:

```
define("SomeCollection", ["localstorage"], function() {
    var SomeCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        localStorage: new Backbone.LocalStorage("SomeCollection") // Unique name within your app.
    });

    return SomeCollection;
});
```

Require your collection:

```
require(["SomeCollection"], function(SomeCollection) {
  // ready to use SomeCollection
});
```

**forth way**

Download js file from GitHub and put it to your library files directory after require it us js file like this

```
var domStorage = requier('yourLibPath/backbone.domStorage.js');
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but i'm using browserify to bundle everything in a single file (app.js). First solution is not possible. Second solution could be good, but it doesn't work with `backbone.domStorage`. It works with `backbone.localstorage` but i need session storage which isn't supported. Third way, not possible, i don't want to use requireJs. How can i make it works with 2nd solution ??

Comment: Just download backbone.domStorage.js and require it like this var domStorage = requier('path to your lib files/ backbone.domStorage.js') ;

Comment: @LoSTxMiND plz check 4 way.

Comment: I already tried the fourth way and it doesn't work because the code isn't not CommonJs compliant. I think i will try one of these solutions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171213/load-vanilla-javascript-libraries-into-node-js?rq=1